# Get id on my login system

Tags: php, mysql

I have to make a login system on my website, but my users don't have the same things on their sites so I will `$_GET` my users' customers_id  (from database) in the URL when they are logged in.

But I cannot see how.

my login code is this.

```
    <?php
$email = $_POST['user'];
$password= $_POST['pass'];
$login = $_POST['login'];
$user_custermers_id = $_GET['id'];

if($login == 'Login' || isset($login)) 
{
    global $wpdb;

    $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM das_custermer_users WHERE email = '$email' AND password ='" . md5($password)."'") or die(mysql_error());


    $result = mysql_num_rows($get);
    if($result == 0)
    {
        $msg = "Wrong E-mail or Password";
    }
    else
    {
        session_start();


        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

        header("location: http://dashboard.tg.com");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should take a look at SQL injections. You have build a brilliant one.

Comment: If this is really your login site, I wouldn't like to be your user :-) You do no escaping, no checking, nothing with the user data.

Comment: it is only to give my employees their work for a week so nothing special secret

Answer (score 1):

You're writing really bad and dangerous code. What if I catch $_POST['email'] and change it to '--;DELETE your_data_base; ?

1. You don't check what data you have and SQL injection is possible in your example.

   ```
   if($login == 'Login' || isset($login))
   ```
2. this condition is without sense because if there is $login== 'login' then isset is TRUE so second OR condition is unneccesary

   session_start();
3. you should move it to 1st line.
4. global is an old PHP syntax avoid it.
5. $user_custermers_id = $_GET['id']; this is really bad. You should cast to to int or use intval()
6. If I were you I would use PDO connection. PDO has PDOStatement::rowCount you can use this property to check if there are any rows.

PDO throws exceptions so mysql_errror() is not needed. mysql_num_rows() is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future so avoid it.

I found this sample in internet. This code should be also in try catch block to handle exceptions

```
$login = mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['login']));
$pass = mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['pass']));

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', 'user', 'pass');
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE login = ? AND pass = ?");
$sth->bindParam(1, $login);
$sth->bindParam(2, md5($pass));
$sth->execute();

if ($sth->rowCount() > 0)
{
  // session stuff,
// refresh page
}
```

Comment: i will do it safe before i take my site online.. :)

Comment: If you don't it's like you were inviting ppl to check what's inside your db ;P

Comment: :P i think i do what you say :P

Comment: The best way is to use framework like Zend Framework or Symfony. They have a lot of already written tools including security.

Comment: Yes they are free but it is not easy for beginners to use them however they give a lot of advantages.